# How to fix/resume a stopped do-release-upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dependencies

I was trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 using do-release-upgrade, but then had to stop it in the middle. I can't resume it now.

```
 ~  iitpi sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
 ✘  ~  iitpi sudo apt upgrade       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat : Conflicts: packagekit
                              Conflicts: packagekit:i386
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: There are a few things you can try depending on the point it was stopped. The better and way faster solution is backup and install from scratch.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any hints on how to fix it besides reinstalling?

Answer (score 5):

For me, what it fixed it was a simple

```
apt update
apt install python3-aptdaemon
```

Then with `apt upgrade` all seemed fine.